# How to get text elements of the same row as selected checkboxes on submiting form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, row

I want to store(in array) the values of the all text elements which are in the same row as selected checkbox. But I can't get those text elements. I know only thing is that I need to work on javascript to get those text. But HOW?
I'm using this code only to get rowIndex and It is not working even.

```js
function func()
{
    var checkbox = $(this);
    other_elements_in_the_row = checkbox.closest("td").siblings().children();
    alert(rowIndex);
}
```

```html
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="ch" value="Akshay" onclick="func(this)"></td>                                   
   <td>ABC</td>                                   
   <td><input type="text" name="txt" ></td>                                 
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="ch" value="Vaghasiya"></td>                                   
   <td>ABC</td>                                   
   <td><input type="text" name="txt" ></td>                                 
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
<input type="submit" name="sub"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purely javascript way:

http://jsfiddle.net/dzLyu8zw/

```
function submit(){
var arr=new Array();
var a= document.querySelectorAll('td > input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    var b= a[i].parentNode.parentNode;
    arr.push(b.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value);        
}
alert(arr);
}
```

Comment: You answer me exactly what I'm looking for. But when I run code on your link, it works. But in my comp, it's still not working.